# Is there a difference between an hour and a time?

Tags: vocabulary

I was wondering which word(s) can be used in the following context:

"Next week we could meet on Monday 6 o'clock and Wednesday 4 o'clock. What do you say? Are these hours/times fine with you?"

Comment: In English, we meet **at a time**.  Also, please look up the words in a dictionary to find an answer. Is this okay with you? Not fine.

Comment: I did look up in the Camridge dictionary. Both "a time" and "an hour" can imply a period of time acoording to it. I found it confusing. In my mother tongue we can use either word. That is why I posted a question on here. So, as I understand, the sentence "Are these times okay with you?" would be the only right one. Thanks

Comment: [I did look them  up in x] :)

Comment: An hour is 60 minutes.  'A time' can mean a period of time, but it usually means a certain point in time, like your 'Monday at 6 o'clock'. Using 'hour' in this sense is obsolete in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of your example, we would not say "*these hours*".

We use 'hours' in various ways, but one meaning is set periods of time - for example, the period of time that an employee works each day may be referred to as 'their hours':

> We expect you to work from 9am until 5pm. Are these hours okay with you?

In your case, you are referring just to a start time - the time at which you meet and begin your time together. We would just refer to that as "*a time*":

> We could meet at 4pm or 6pm - are either of these times okay with you?

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your answer :)